# Como descargar una rama que esta en el repositorio remoto y no localmente?

Tags: git

He intentado hacer

```
git fetch
```

Y luego

```
git checkout -b <nombre de la rama> origin/<nombre de la rama>
```

Pero no funciona ya que obtengo este error:

```
fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs' : 'ref exist' cannot create refs
```

Al hacer `git checkout` obtengo el mismo error, no se que pasa

Comment: Parece que la rama que estas pidiendo no existe en el remoto. Podrías colocar la salida de este comando en la pregunta? `git branch -r` Y el comando y salida del `git checkout` que estás intentando.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO!

Comment: Bueno.... en realidad el mensaje me hace pensar que hay un error de permisos local. Tú eres el dueño (usuario local) de ese directorio donde estás trabajando?

Comment: Definitivamente quiero ver el comando de checkout que estás intentando y su salida _tal cual_.

Comment: Eso se debe a que la rama ya la tienes `ref exist`, usa el comando `git rev-parse origin/<nombre de la rama>`  si te devuelve un ID, debemos "borrarlo" asi que usa el comando `git update-ref -d origin/<nombre de la rama>` Y ya `git fetch` debería funcionar correctamente

Comment: Ten en cuenta que al indicarle -b a checkout, estas tratando de crear una rama nueva, no sólo cambiándote de rama. Si ya realizaste el fetch, bastaría con indicar git checkout nombre-rama y listo.